# Button texts disappear on KitKat (API level 19)

Tags: java, android, button, android-4.4-kitkat

The main menu of my app (a game) uses standard Android buttons. It works fine on all my devices except on *Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2*. The issue is as follows:

The text of a button suddenly disappears in either of these cases:

- the button is pressed (it happens immediately when I touch it, no need to release it),
- `setEnabled(boolean)` is called on the button

For example, if I press "Load game", the button is correctly highlighted during the press event, but "Load game" disappears completely (the button has empty text).

If I remove all custom styles and behaviors, and use only the default Android buttons with default font etc., the problem still persists.

*If I decrease targetSdkVersion to 18 (from 19), everything works fine even on Nexus 7.*

Any idea what has changed in KitKat in this respect? I didn't find anything suspicious.

My revalant XML code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutGameMainmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="83dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadGame"
            android:layout_width="174dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gamemainmenu"
            android:text="buttonLoadGame"
            android:textColor="@color/button_gamemainmenu_text"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
            android:layout_width="174dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gamemainmenu"
            android:text="buttonSettings"
            android:textColor="@color/button_gamemainmenu_text"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStartGame"
            android:layout_width="174dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gamemainmenu"
            android:text="buttonStartGame"
            android:textColor="@color/button_gamemainmenu_text"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonQuit"
            android:layout_width="174dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_gamemainmenu"
            android:text="buttonQuit"
            android:textColor="@color/button_gamemainmenu_text"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Important notes regarding the above code:

- The game has a two-row main menu (with two buttons in each row, so altogether 4 buttons), and this main menu is positioned on the bottom of the screen
- Literal texts are placeholders only, because the game has an own file format for texts, and reads data from there when the Activity is created
- **The issue persists** even if I completely remove the `android:textColor` and `android:background` attributes. In this case, my buttons will have a default appearance (instead of their game specific style), but the issue persists.
- To emphasize again: the above code works perfectly on all (tested) devices except Nexus 7 (all my devices except Nexus 7 are pre-KitKat devices)

Finally, some information about my global styles/themes:

In AndroidManifest, I set my `Application` theme to `MyCustomTheme`. The content of `mycustomtheme.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Finally, my `styles.xml` is as follows (but it seems I don't refer its styles from anywhere, this seems to be old code from the time we made the game fullscreen, or does Android use it anywhere by default?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.TranslucentWoTitle" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you provide your xml and your code please. Also is text on button empty after or invisible. Try to call getText() from button and look is text empty.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The problem with TextView measured it's height wrong when it had no text set, and not re-measured correctly after text was set. Try setting a stub text in xml like android:text="test" and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a _new project_? If you can, please post that minimal code. If you can't there's something else wrong in your project. For me, starting a new Hello World project, and changing the default `TextView` into a `Button` does not reproduce it, on a Nexus 7 2013 4.4.2.

Comment: post your code buddy..!!

Comment: Thanks for comments. I checked all that stuff (getText(), text visibility, stub text, etc.) Niek Haarman, you're right, a "minimum-code" project would be essential, but I don't have enough time for that until the product's release. BTW can you confirm that your API Level was set 19 (and not lower) in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Added XML code. Thanks for reminding me to this, *Demand* and *Dev Carlsberg*.

Comment: What background color is your button and what do you use as foreground color?

Comment: Background is an image which depends on the button state, and foreground color is black. **Please** don't forget, however, that if I remove all these settings, and let Android use its default attributes, the problem persists.

Comment: Have you checked your stack trace on logcat to ensure that you are getting outofmemory exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your XML file, I still believe that there is something going wrong in your project.

---

This minimal example does not reproduce the problem on a Nexus 7 2013 4.4.2 (`minSDK=8`, `targetSDK=19`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Taking your XML and removing backgrounds / textcolors does not reproduce it either:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutGameMainmenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="83dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLoadGame"
                android:layout_width="174dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                android:text="buttonLoadGame"
                android:textScaleX="0.9"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
                android:layout_width="174dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:text="buttonSettings"
                android:textScaleX="0.9"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonStartGame"
                android:layout_width="174dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                android:text="buttonStartGame"
                android:textScaleX="0.9"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonQuit"
                android:layout_width="174dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:text="buttonQuit"
                android:textScaleX="0.9"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Lastly, I'm noticing `android:textColor="button_gamemainmenu_text"`, which is not default Android behavior and suggests that you're handling text color in your own way. I strongly believe that removing this custom behavior will solve the problem.

Comment: Two comments: 1) you're right, something may be wrong with the project (it's a huge project, the game also uses a GLSurfaceView etc.). Too bad that only KitKat triggers the issue. 2) You mention my non-default Android behavior with textColor, but please read the comments below my XML code. I mention there that the problem persists even if I remove all textColor and background attributes.  I don't see any other custom stuff in my XML code.

Comment: You're right about the textColor, but having that `String` as attribute value in the first place suggests that you're handling text color in _java_ code yourself. Disable that as well. -- Another minor hunch - try playing with hardware acceleration (true/false in manifest, `setLayerType(..)`, device developer settings..)

Comment: BTW I would welcome hints what I should remove from my project as a test. As I said, the project is so huge that I can't easily remove its parts (a hobby game we've been developing with 5 friends since Dec 2013).

Comment: My Activity onCreate() has these (removing DITHER didn't help; it's needed for an old Android device BTW):

window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN  
                 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD 
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER); 
   
     window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

Comment: Remove it :) See what happens. I'm assuming you're using some version control like Git, so no harm done.

Comment: BTW, could you clarify what you mean by disabling the String attribute value? Do you mean the android:text part?

Comment: No, instead of something like `android:textColor="@color/mycolor"` or `android:textColor="#aabbcc"`, you have `android:textColor="button_gamemainmenu_text"`, which is not default Android behavior to my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo there! I've just corrected it. In my actual project, there was no typo. It was all @color/.... Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Then I can only imagine it has something to do with Hardware Acceleration, or you're forgetting about some `Button` customization in `styles.xml`.

Comment: I added xml code of my style/theme related files to my initial post, please check them.

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? Using the themes as you posted in your question, would give you very old button designs. Perhaps there's another `styles.xml` in `values-vxx`? Do you set a theme in your `AndroidManifest?`

Comment: The manifest refers to MyCustomTheme. I don't have any other styles folder or file. Regarding the "minimized" environment to reproduce the error, I don't have the time for that before the product's release; this is a huge Eclipse project currently, it takes much time to remove parts etc.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to live with this then. It's clearly somewhere hidden in your project, because a new project does not reproduce it.

Comment: Once I get more time, I'll start dealing with this issue again. Until then, product will have targetSdkLevel 18.

Comment: I removed the window flag changes from Activity.onCreate(), removed my main app theme, forced GPU rendering via Dev Options of the device, and then tried with "disable HW overlays", and finally I removed my game's GLSurfaceView temporarily. Nothing worked so far. It seems there is a need to strip the huge project to its minimum size, testing continuously the incremental changes.

Comment: Moreover, I removed the unnecessary (unused) *styles.xml* as well. There are no additional values-xxx folders, so the issue shouldn't be due to those.

Comment: are you added any selectors for button?

Comment: There are, but if I remove the selectors (remove references to them, completely), the error persists.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could get some new insights using the "Hierarchy View" - Perspective in Eclipse to debug your layout? It's quite useful as you can read the measured layout parameters at runtime. At least it should guide you to the right track.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind. (I hope I can get the time soon to try it.)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue. The text disappears on Nexus 7 & Nexus 10.

Scenario in which the bug occurred:

1. Use the following layout.
2. Set text to the textView on the click of the button.

   ```
   <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button1"
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Record"
               android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:text="TextView" />
   ```

To fix the issue, you could either switch from `TableLayout to LinearLayout` or
set width for your buttons. This was what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have tested this with your custom styles. I have used hardcoded color because i could not use the text color what you have used. it is working on all devices. i could not test it on nexus 7. because i dont have this device. Hopefully it will work in nexus7. Kindly check with updated file and let me know the feedback. If you have used any selectors then post the selectors files.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cccccc"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutGameMainmenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLoadGame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:text="buttonLoadGame"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:text="buttonSettings"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonStartGame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
            android:text="buttonStartGame"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonQuit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:text="buttonQuit"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textScaleX="0.9"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'll try to return to the issue in the near future. I use selectors, but even if I disable (remove) the completely, the issue still persists.